# Call Cronjob URL in PHP?

Tags: php, url, cron

I want to call one cronjob in my PHP script via an URL. Because I do not know how the function is behaving, I am asking here.

Is there a way, and if yes, how, to call a URL and get the content of the requested URL?

Furthermore the cronjob needs very long. So I do not know what happens after e.g. 15 mins. if the function is still not getting a response from the URL. Do I have to worry about it or is the function waiting?

The URL is the key to start the cron and at the end of the cron I get something like "200" back.

Comment: You could just enter it in a browser like any URL and it will execute. You can add code to output things so you can debug in your browser. I'd definitely do something like `echo "done";` at the end so you know it's done if it takes as long as you say it does. That way you'll at least know it finished executing.

Comment: You can log the return of the cron with `>> filelocation/andname.log` after the call. e.g. `php /var/www/cron/myscript.php >> /home/chris/what_did_i_do.log`

Comment: I am assuming when you say cronjob you actually mean "very long task" because cronjobs are just scheduled tasks that don't typically need to be ran manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could just enter it in a browser like any URL and it will execute.

You can add code to output things so you can debug in your browser.

As for making sure the code executes, you can add a simple `echo "done";` at the end so you know it finished executing if it takes as long as you say it does.

If you have any errors, as long as you have error reporting on, they'll be displayed in the browser.